# How to know if imagick throws an error - PHP

Tags: php, imagick

I am currently using `imagick` for image processing on my webssite. I have it correctly installed and is working great. Heres my starting code -:

```
$image = new imagick($filename); $geo=$image->getImageGeometry();  
$image->setImageInterlaceScheme(2);  $image->setImageCompressionQuality(85);
$image->setImageBackgroundColor('white'); $image = $image->flattenImages(); 
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');   $image->stripImage();
```

After this i do the rest of the part. Now suppose it throws an error, how do i code for that. I tried adding `if(!$image){ echo 'error' exit(); }` after `$image = new imagick($filename)` but in vain.

Please help... Thanks all :)

Answer (score 13):

If an error occurs, Imagick will throw an `ImagickException` which you can catch:

```
    try {
        $image = new Imagick($filename);
        $geo = $image->getImageGeometry();  
        $image->setImageInterlaceScheme(2);  
        $image->setImageCompressionQuality(85);
        $image->setImageBackgroundColor('white'); 
        $image = $image->flattenImages(); 
        $image->setImageFormat('jpg');   
        $image->stripImage();
    } catch (ImagickException $e) 
{
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

for further reference see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php).

Comment: The ImagickException seems undocumented (on php.net at least).