# How do I skip CRC check while processing images

Tags: php, imagick, crc

I have a program which processes images with imagick in PHP:

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($fileSystem->read($file));
```

This process raises an error on CRC errors:

```
IDAT: CRC error `' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1643
```

There is nothing wrong with this image and I want to process it just like the rest of them, I don't care that the CRC check fails.

Comment: How exactly are you using imagick (show code!), and is this error actually an exception? If so, catch it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887228/how-to-know-if-imagick-throws-an-error-php

Comment: How can we reproduce this? Please add your PHP code

Comment: I updated the question with the code where I create the imagick image. I do catch the errors but I cannot proceed with this image once it failed loading into imagick. I would like to tell imagick not tho check the file hash. There are image manipulation programs which do not update this hash and all of those files are then 'corrupt'.

Comment: To reproduce you need a 'corrupt' image file, i don't think I can upload one here.

Comment: "there is nothing wrong with this image": well, the CRC is wrong. But if you can open it in another program, you could save it there and hopefully create a correct header. Is this only one file where you have this problem, so a manual solution would be acceptable?

Comment: It is a program which processed large amount of files daily, so fixing every image by hand is no solution. I can imagine that there could be files which are indeed corrupt who fail this CRC check, but while randomly checking these corrupt files I came across none.